# forcePasteAsPlainText is not considered in Chrome with Ctrl +V

Tags: google-chrome, ckeditor

I set up two ckeditors on my page and activated the option forcePasteAsPlainText: true. I expect that when I copy text, all tags, e. g. bold, are removed when I paste the text. Unfortunately this does not work in all browsers, especially not in Chrome (50.0.2661.75 or older version 49.0.2623.110). I use CKEditor 4.5.8.

When I copy text from one to the other editor using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in Chrome  the complete html is inserted, including bold tag. In Firefox and IE it is removed as expected.

[Screenshot Chrome behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rvtX.png)

Take a look at my [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/coachtomato/v0on0wtz/).

```
window.CKEDITOR.replace( 'cke1',
{
    forcePasteAsPlainText: true
});

window.CKEDITOR.replace( 'cke2',
{
    forcePasteAsPlainText: true
});
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: I found out in the meantime that the problem only occurs inside of the same browser tab. When I have two browser tabs opened, it also works in Chrome. Furthermore the problem occurs in Safari and Opera as well.

Answer (score 0):

After some checking it turned out there are two issues in CKEditor for Blink and Webkit browsers which have started occurring from CKEditor 4.5.0: 
https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13969, https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/14293.